# Why does Blank sometimes not match the empty expression?

Tags: pattern-matching

Consider these examples:

```
MatchQ[, _]                   (* True *)
MatchQ[{wald}, {_Symbol}]     (* True *)
MatchQ[5, _Integer]           (* True *)
MatchQ[{wald}, _{_Symbol}]    (* False *)
```

Why does Mathematica not see the fourth pattern as valid, namely as a pattern restricted to be a list consisting of a `Symbol` (or alternatively, as an empty expression followed by a list of a `Symbol`)?

I am using Mathematica 12.2.

Comment: Look at `FullForm[_{_Symbol}]`. I think it's different than what you think it is, maybe.

Comment: did you mean `_[_Symbol]`?

Answer (score 7):

One source of confusion here is about what `MatchQ[, _]` actually does. Contrary to what you think, the first argument of MatchQ here is not "the empty expression" (which isn't a thing in WL) but it's `Null`.

Consider, for example:

```
{, 1}
Hold[, 1]
```

> {Null, 1}

> Hold[Null, 1]

`Null` is a special value that doesn't get printed when it's returned to the FE as the result of an evaluation, but it will get printed if it's part of an expression:

```
Null (* no output *)
```

```
{Null}
```

> {Null}

So `MatchQ[, _]`is just `MatchQ[Null, _]`, which is obviously `True`.

The closest thing you get to an "empty expression" is `Sequence[]`, which disappears whenever it is enclosed by a head that does not have the `SequenceHold` attribute:

```
f[Sequence[]]
HoldComplete[Sequence[]]
```

> f[]

> HoldComplete[Sequence[]]

but on its own it's still a non-empty expression:

```
Sequence[]
```

> Sequence[]

Answer (score 6):

Your pattern is actually interpreted as a multiplication:

```
FullForm[_{_Symbol}]

(* List[Times[Blank, Blank[Symbol]]] *)
```

To match a list consisting of a Symbol, use `List[_Symbol]` as a pattern:

```
MatchQ[{wald}, List[_Symbol]]
(* True *)
```